# how to add two coordinates (x,y) to a arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, random, rgb, awtrobot

My code reads all the pixels from the screen until it finds a pixel with the RGB value that I specified, which I managed to do, however if my screen has multiple pixels of that RGB value, I want to be able select a **random** pixel within that RBG value, instead of only working with the first pixel that my code finds I want to work with a random one. A workaround that I made generates a random number between 1 and 100 and everytime it checks a pixel it has a 1% chance of working with it, however this isn't the best method because of the way that my code scans the screen, (top-down, left-right) that means most of the time the pixel will end up on the upper left corner with isn't exactly random. I thought a good solution would be evertime the code goes through the if statement it stores the values x,y in a arraylist then I would get a random Index from that arraylist, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.
I appreciate any suggestions and help :)

```
            int rng = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
            
            if (color.equals(iron) && rng == 5){
                if (r != 215 || g != 215 || b != 215){
                    Robot move = new Robot();
                    mousemoving.mouseGlide(x,y,1250,1000);
                    Runecraft.randomInt(35, 481);
                    move.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    move.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

                    System.out.println(iron);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
```

Comment: You can create a class/record that just has two ints representing the coordinate, and put instances of that class into an ArrayList. Or if you wouldn't even bother with that, make two Arraylists, one for x-axis and one for y, though the code would an atrocity.

Comment: (1) Count the number of pixels with the specified RGB-value = num. (2) Generate a random number x between 0 and num-1 (3) Go through all pixels again, and if pixels equals RGB, then increase i, until (4) i equals x, then take coordinates of this pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to add two coordinates (x,y) to a arraylist

Check out the [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Point.html) or [Point2D](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) classes.  They have exactly what you want.

Then

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
```